# Пересечение временных интервалов

Tags: php

Есть массив времени:

```
$arTimes[0]["START"] = 1515486600 //09.01.2018 11:30
$arTimes[0]["END"] = 1515488400   //09.01.2018 12:00
$arTimes[1]["START"] = 1515488400 //09.01.2018 12:00
$arTimes[1]["END"] = 1515488400   //09.01.2018 12:30
$arTimes[2]["START"] = 1515486600 //09.01.2018 11:30
$arTimes[2]["END"] = 1515490200   //09.01.2018 12:30
```

В данном контексте `$arTimes[0]` не пересекается с `$arTimes[1]` но пересекается с `$arTimes[2]`, и `$arTimes[1]` пересекается с `$arTimes[2]`.

Необходимо узнать все пересечения рекурсивно, то есть если `$arTimes[0]` пересекся с `$arTimes[2]`, то далее нужно узнать с кем пересекается `$arTimes[2]` и т.д.

Цель, если есть пересечения у элемента `$arTimes[0]` то установить `$arTimes[0]["NEW_START"]` = наименьший START и `$arTimes[0]["NEW_END"]` наибольший END из всех элементов которые пересеклись друг с другом.

Так же, прикрепить эти элементы к `$arTimes[0]["ELEM"][] = $arTimes[2]` и т.д., затем удалить их из массива `$arTimes`, что бы более не сравнивать интервалы.

Как же это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых ошибка в исходных данных: `$arTimes[1]["END"] = 1515488400   //09.01.2018 12:30` это не 12:30

Должно быть так:

```
$arTimes[0]["START"] = 1515486600; //09.01.2018 11:30
$arTimes[0]["END"] = 1515488400 ;  //09.01.2018 12:00
$arTimes[1]["START"] = 1515488400; //09.01.2018 12:00
$arTimes[1]["END"] = 1515490200;   //09.01.2018 12:30
$arTimes[2]["START"] = 1515486600; //09.01.2018 11:30
$arTimes[2]["END"] = 1515490200;   //09.01.2018 12:30
```

Потом в рекурсии сравниваем интервалы времени:

```
function chain($index) {
    global $arTimes, $freezeIndex;

    $time = $arTimes[$index];

    if(!isset($time)) {
        return;
    }

    foreach($arTimes AS $indexTime => $value) {

        if(!in_array($indexTime, $freezeIndex) && $indexTime != $index && max($value["START"], $time["START"]) < min($value["END"], $time["END"])) {
            $freezeIndex[] = $indexTime;

            if($time["START"] > $value["START"]) {
                $arTimes[0]["NEW_START"] = $value["START"];
            }

            if($time["END"] < $value["END"]) {
                $arTimes[0]["NEW_END"] = $value["END"];
            }

            echo "Пересекаются " . $index . " и " . $indexTime . "\n";

            chain($indexTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и посмотреть: https://ideone.com/W8DESm

Comment: Спасибо! Но, смотрю массив и там "космическое" время почему то получается 2031 год и т.д: array(14) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["START"]=>
    int(1064890345)
    ["END"]=>
    int(1776793966)
    ["NEW_END"]=>
    int(1951002612)
    ["NEW_START"]=>
    int(1080240959)
  }

Comment: Так у меня в примере random от 1000000000 до 2000000000 секунд.